# A chamber to control concentration of a vapor: Is there a name for this equipment?

Tags: vapor-pressure, equipment, reaction-control, chemical-engineering

Mechanical engineer here so please excuse me if my question seems dumb to you!

I want to have a chamber $(\approx 40 \times 30 \times \pu{30 cm})$ to control concentration $(\pu{ppm})$ of a flammable material (e.g. alcohols or ketones) at a specific temperature $(T\approx \pu{24 \pm 10 ^\circ C})$ and pressure $(P\approx \pu{1 \pm 0.5 bar})$

> [image]

What should this chamber be called? I need the the name to be able to search for it and also mention in my publication.

Candidate names so far:

- Incubator --> mostly for biological entities
- Reactor
- Environmental chamber --> too expensive
- Atmospheric controlled chamber
- Autoclave --> for sterilization(high temperature/pressure)
- Flash drum
- Vapor inhalation chambers --> for animal testing

P.S. I have posted the question also on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChemicalEngineering/comments/7ij3m3/a_chamber_to_control_concentration_of_a_vapor_is/?st=jb01somf&sh=a9c0ae8a) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/7iix6a/a_chamber_to_control_concentration_of_a_vapor_is/?st=jb01sqjh&sh=7b8cbc85). There are some good points mentioned there.

Comment: Maybe [environmental chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_chamber)? Welcome to Chemistry.SE by the way:)

Comment: @andselisk thanks for not burning me to the ground :) other SO communities are really hostile to newcomers. Environmental chamber seems very close to what I need. but it seems very expensive. Are there any smaller versions ($\approx 40 \times 30 \times 30 cm$) with not too many requirements?

Comment: Good question; I don't really know, I'm sorry. I used a big one only once a decade ago, and yep, those were and are remaining expensive. Probably you can find a good deal on [LabX](http://www.labx.com/), it's like an eBay for lab equipment.

Comment: they are indeed expensive! Thanks. I will keep searching.

Comment: I would probably also add the dimensions or the volume of the chamber to the question. Also, the information whether the liquid and the vapors are corrosive might come in handy.

Comment: @andselisk are Alcohol or Acetone corrosive?

Comment: Not really, they can dissolve some plastics though. If you intend to use them, I would just add both as the examples to the question.

Comment: @andselisk I also mentioned that they are flammable.

Comment: I think the term is autoclave. This is normally for high pressure processes. If you are running at about atmospheric P and just controlling the partial P of substances I would suggest controlled atmosphere chamber.

Answer (score 6):

There is a book [The Design of Controlled-atmosphere Chambers for the Study of Oxygen Toxicity](https://books.google.com/books?id=fbhjAAAAMAAJ&q=controlled%20atmosphere%20chamber&dq=controlled%20atmosphere%20chamber&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRhbbgnPvXAhWEQt8KHUAKCt8Q6AEIJzAA), so I suggest "contolled-atmosphere chamber".

Comment: Thanks @davephd , I'm not able to find the source on the internet. is it a theses or something? do you have the PDF? It seems there are no off the shelve solution for me and I have to make anyway!

Comment: Searching `controlled atmospheric chamber` on google mostly refers to glove boxes made by `Plas-Labs`.  that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: from [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChemicalEngineering/comments/7ij3m3/a_chamber_to_control_concentration_of_a_vapor_is/dr05cgh/?st=jb028e1r&sh=8df2350a): `typically atmospheric tends to be reserved for situations where atmospheric gases are used instead of organic vapors`